# Tabulating Profit And Loss For Backtesting using Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, back-testing

I have this Bigquery dataframe where 1 in long_entry or short_entry represents entering the trade at that time with a long/short position corresponding. While a 1 in long_exit or short_exit means exiting a trade. I would like to have 2 new columns, one called long_pnl which tabulate the PnL generated from individual long trades and another called short_pnl which tabulate the PnL generated from individual short trades.

Only a maximum of 1 trade/position at any point of time for this backtesting.

Below is my dataframe. As we can see, a long trade is entered on 26/2/2019 and closed at 1/3/2019 and the Pnl will be $64.45 while a short trade is entered on 4/3/2019 and closed on 5/3/2019 with a pnl of -$119.11 (loss).

```
        date    price       long_entry  long_exit   short_entry short_exit
0   24/2/2019   4124.25           0          0           0              0
1   25/2/2019   4130.67           0          0           0              0
2   26/2/2019   4145.67           1          0           0              0
3   27/2/2019   4180.10           0          0           0              0
4   28/2/2019   4200.05           0          0           0              0
5   1/3/2019    4210.12           0          1           0              0
6   2/3/2019    4198.10           0          0           0              0
7   3/3/2019    4210.34           0          0           0              0
8   4/3/2019    4100.12           0          0           1              0
9   5/3/2019    4219.23           0          0           0              1
```

I hope to have an output like this, with another column for short_pnl:

```
        date    price       long_entry  long_exit   short_entry short_exit  long_pnl         
0   24/2/2019   4124.25           0          0           0             0    NaN  
1   25/2/2019   4130.67           0          0           0             0    NaN
2   26/2/2019   4145.67           1          0           0             0  64.45
3   27/2/2019   4180.10           0          0           0             0    NaN
4   28/2/2019   4200.05           0          0           0             0    NaN
5   1/3/2019    4210.12           0          1           0             0    NaN
6   2/3/2019    4198.10           0          0           0             0    NaN
7   3/3/2019    4210.34           0          0           0             0    NaN
8   4/3/2019    4100.12           0          0           1             0    NaN
9   5/3/2019    4219.23           0          0           0             1    NaN
```

Comment: might be naive question  - but why 64.45 positive and 119.11 negative - they both look to me as positive? please clarify

Comment: Short means you sell at the current price, and you buy when you close your short trade. Hence, you are selling at $4100.12 and buying at $4219.23 which is a loss

Comment: got it. love to learn something new for me :o)

Comment: Do you think you can help me with this?

Comment: sure, looks doable. someone will definitely answers. I will also check this closely shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH temp1 AS (
  SELECT PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y', dt) dt, CAST(price AS numeric) price, long_entry, long_exit, short_entry, short_exit
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
), temp2 AS (
  SELECT dt, price, long_entry, long_exit, short_entry, short_exit,
    SUM(long_entry) OVER(ORDER BY dt) + SUM(long_exit) OVER(ORDER BY dt ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) long_grp,
    SUM(short_entry) OVER(ORDER BY dt) + SUM(short_exit) OVER(ORDER BY dt ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) short_grp
  FROM temp1
)
SELECT dt, price, long_entry, long_exit, short_entry, short_exit,
  IF(long_entry = 0, NULL, 
    FIRST_VALUE(price) OVER(PARTITION BY long_grp ORDER BY dt DESC) - 
    LAST_VALUE(price) OVER(PARTITION BY long_grp ORDER BY dt DESC)
  ) long_pnl,
  IF(short_entry = 0, NULL, 
    LAST_VALUE(price) OVER(PARTITION BY short_grp ORDER BY dt DESC) - 
    FIRST_VALUE(price) OVER(PARTITION BY short_grp ORDER BY dt DESC)
  ) short_pnl
FROM temp2
```

If to apply above to sample data in your question

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '24/2/2019' dt, 4124.25 price, 0 long_entry, 0 long_exit, 0 short_entry, 0 short_exit UNION ALL
  SELECT '25/2/2019', 4130.67, 0, 0, 0, 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT '26/2/2019', 4145.67, 1, 0, 0, 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT '27/2/2019', 4180.10, 0, 0, 0, 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT '28/2/2019', 4200.05, 0, 0, 0, 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT '1/3/2019', 4210.12, 0, 1, 0, 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2/3/2019', 4198.10, 0, 0, 0, 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT '3/3/2019', 4210.34, 0, 0, 0, 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT '4/3/2019', 4100.12, 0, 0, 1, 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT '5/3/2019', 4219.23, 0, 0, 0, 1 
), temp1 AS (
  SELECT PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y', dt) dt, CAST(price AS numeric) price, long_entry, long_exit, short_entry, short_exit
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
), temp2 AS (
  SELECT dt, price, long_entry, long_exit, short_entry, short_exit,
    SUM(long_entry) OVER(ORDER BY dt) + SUM(long_exit) OVER(ORDER BY dt ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) long_grp,
    SUM(short_entry) OVER(ORDER BY dt) + SUM(short_exit) OVER(ORDER BY dt ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) short_grp
  FROM temp1
)
SELECT dt, price, long_entry, long_exit, short_entry, short_exit,
  IF(long_entry = 0, NULL, 
    FIRST_VALUE(price) OVER(PARTITION BY long_grp ORDER BY dt DESC) - 
    LAST_VALUE(price) OVER(PARTITION BY long_grp ORDER BY dt DESC)
  ) long_pnl,
  IF(short_entry = 0, NULL, 
    LAST_VALUE(price) OVER(PARTITION BY short_grp ORDER BY dt DESC) - 
    FIRST_VALUE(price) OVER(PARTITION BY short_grp ORDER BY dt DESC)
  ) short_pnl
FROM temp2
-- ORDER BY dt
```

result will be

```
Row dt          price   long_entry  long_exit   short_entry short_exit  long_pnl    short_pnl    
1   2019-02-24  4124.25 0           0           0           0           null        null     
2   2019-02-25  4130.67 0           0           0           0           null        null     
3   2019-02-26  4145.67 1           0           0           0           64.45       null     
4   2019-02-27  4180.1  0           0           0           0           null        null     
5   2019-02-28  4200.05 0           0           0           0           null        null     
6   2019-03-01  4210.12 0           1           0           0           null        null     
7   2019-03-02  4198.1  0           0           0           0           null        null     
8   2019-03-03  4210.34 0           0           0           0           null        null     
9   2019-03-04  4100.12 0           0           1           0           null        -119.11  
10  2019-03-05  4219.23 0           0           0           1           null        null
```

I feel there should be a "shorter" solution - but above is still good enough I think to use

Comment: Hi Sir, could you share with me how does the long_group and short_group work? How does sum(long_entry) + sum(long_exit) form the group? Thank you

Comment: the best way to see how it works is to run step by step and see intermediate results. the script is quite simple and self-descriptive  - you should play with it by yourself to get insight - if you will have specific question during that "journey" - i will be glad to help by explaining